# Sorting the Dates in Array

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, sorting

**I have an array as follow which comes from Sqlite DB & are in string:**

```
(

{ 
 id=1;
duedate = "01-Apr-2013";
},

{
 id=2;
duedate = "01-May-2013";
},

{
id=3;
duedate = "01-Jun-2013";
},

{
 id=4;
duedate = "11-Jul-2013";
}

)
```

**My code for sorting the array**

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"duedate" ascending:YES];
[assessment_list sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDesc]];
```

**But This give wrong sorted array as follow**

```
(

{ 
 id=1;
duedate = "01-Apr-2013";
},

{
id=3;
duedate = "01-Jun-2013";
},

{
id=2;
duedate = "01-May-2013";
},

{
 id=4;
duedate = "11-Jul-2013";
}

)
```

**I searched but i didn't found this issue**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because it is sorted alphabetically.

For sorting on dates, you need to implement  a method something like this

```
NSInteger dateSort(id dict1, id dict2, void* context){
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"mm/dd/yyyy"];
NSDate *date1 = [formatter dateFromString:[dict1 objectForKey:@"duedate"]];
NSDate *date2 = [formatter dateFromString:[dict2 objectForKey:@"duedate"]];
    return [[date1 compare:date2];
}
```

and call the function like this

```
[dateArray sortUsingFunction:dateSort context:NULL];
```

Comment: what should be written in place of `string1` & `string2`? My array count is 4.

Comment: return [date2 compare:date1] to get it in descending order

Answer (score 2):

You need to do it in parts.

**Part 1** : Convert these strings into `NSDate`.

```
NSDateFormatter *df=[NSDateFormatter new];
[df setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy"];
NSDate *date=[df dateFromString:string];
```

**Part 2** : Then use sorting technique/ way (selector, descriptor etc).

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the strings to date to sort them

```
   NSArray *datesStringArray = @[@{@"duedate": @"01-Jun-2013"},@{@"duedate": @"01-Dec-2013"},@{@"duedate": @"01-Apr-2013"},@{@"duedate": @"11-Jul-2013"},];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy"];

    NSArray *sortedDateStringArray = [datesStringArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {

        NSDictionary *dict1 = (NSDictionary *)obj1;
        NSString *string1 = dict1[@"duedate"];
        NSDictionary *dict2 = (NSDictionary *)obj2;
        NSString *string2 = dict2[@"duedate"];

        NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:string1];
        NSDate *date2 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:string2];

        return [date1 compare:date2];

    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your dates into time interval.

```
int t = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
```

and sort your array like array with int values